# UnBounce and WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a landing page that I am creating in UnBounce. I have created a button on UnBounce and I would like it to go to a shopping cart on my woocommerce page that has the item in it. For example, if I am selling chocolate chip cookies the user would click the "buy now" for chocolate chip cookies on UnBounce and it would take them to a shopping cart on woocommerce with a dozen chocolate chip cookies in it. I would rather this didn't go to the product page (which I know is possibe) - just the shopping cart.
Thank you for you help.

Comment: Should the shopping cart already be populated with a product upon clicking of that link?

Comment: Yes that was my plan. I am happy to do it in whatever way is the easiest. Generally I use UnBounce for lead gen, so for the eCommerce I am open to solutions.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce can add any product to the cart using the following URL http://example.com?add-to-cart=PRODUCT_ID

Unfortunately Unbonce does a mess with `add-to-cart` variable, changing it to `addtocart`.

So you will need a function to receive the Unbounce variables and change them to WooCommerce variables.

Does it make sense to you?

Regards,
Gabriel